# MBP Touch Bar Mirror Displays Keyboard Shorcut

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, shortcut, touch-bar

On the new macbooks with the Touch Bar, what keyboard shortcut can be used to mirror displays?

On Macbook Pros without the touchbar, the keyboard shortcut for mirroring displays was `Command+F1`. This doesn't seem to work on the new Macbook Pro with touchbar - you have to press the `Fn` key to show the `F1`, `F2`, etc. keys, and `Fn+Command+F1` doesn't seem to do it.

Here are my current keyboard settings:

[image: Keyboard settings]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The new shortcut is `Command-Dim Brightness`. It even makes sense in the following way:

Assuming that you take advantage of the touch bar, and it displays the system controls instead of the function keys then **the hand gesture is exactly the same** as before when you would have pressed `Command-F1` since the `Dim Brightness` button is where `F1` would be:

[image]

The annoying thing is that if you have an application-aware touch bar configuration, then you have to bring up the system controls touch bar configuration first.

This is why, in some cases, the [Display Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) (in the App Store) which adds a status item in your menu bar (and includes a Mirror Screen choice) is a good option.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For future reference, this didn't work for me if I had customized the control strip (even if the `Dim Brightness` button was in the same place), I had to be using the "Default Set" configuration.

Comment: Any idea what this maps to on an external keyboard? Neither Cmd+F1 nor Cmd+F14 seems to work

Comment: How do you accomplish this when the touch bar is empty (before the OS is fully running)?  Context: Mac screen is smashed, and is hooked to an external monitor. Everything is fine while the Mac is running. But before it is fully booted, it will not automatically mirror, and there appears to be no option to force it (other than to close the lid; and how do you use the mouse / keyboard with the lid in the way?)

Answer (score 4):

Workaround found, works for me, late 2016 MBP 15":

System Preferences > Keyboard > Press Fn key to > "Show control strip"

fn + Command + "screen brightness less" (where F1 would be otherwise) = toggle mirroring

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea what the shortcut is on external keyboards?

Answer (score 3):

I have the opposite problem.. was lacking a stock option to disable this shortcut!

I've remapped `Cmd,F1` to `display_brightness_decrement` using [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html) - no need to interfere with other shortcuts!

**You can install the key mapping from here: [disable_cmd_f1_screen_mirroring](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#disable_cmd_f1_screen_mirroring) by following instructions here: [configuration-complex-modifications](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html#configuration-complex-modifications).**

Alternatively, to achieve this manually: you can place the following file in `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/disable_cmd_f1_screen_mirroring.json` then activate it via Karabiner Elements:

- Navigate to `Karabiner Elements > Preferences > Complex Modifications > Rules`
- `Add Rule`
- `Enable` your new rule

```
{
    "title": "Disable Cmd+F1 Toggle Screen Mirroring",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "Disable Cmd+F1 Toggle Screen Mirroring Shortcut (map to display_brightness_decrement), see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2793101",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "description": "",
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f1",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "command"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "display_brightness_decrement"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: add rule to Karabiner]

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard Settings

- Touch Bar shows: F1, F2, etc. Keys
- Press Fn key to: Show Control Strip

On MBP keyboard, this works:

fn + cmd + dim brightness

External Microsoft keyboard, TBD.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your options at System Preferences > Keyboard, under the “Keyboard” tab. There’s a checkbox there for “Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys,” and if that’s on, the keyboard shortcut will be Function-Command-F1 instead.

Visit https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/os-x-use-keyboard-shortcut-display-mirroring/

Comment: This doesn't work for the new macbooks (MacOS). Updated the image above with my whole Keyboard tab in System Preferences. That option doesn't exist anywhere (that I can find).

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html) and the utility at https://fabiancanas.com/open-source/mirror-displays to enable Command plus the Dim Brightness button on the Touch Bar.

Instructions:

1. Install the [MirrorDisplays app](https://fabiancanas.com/open-source/mirror-displays) in your Utilities folder
2. In System Preferences for Keyboard, choose Touch Bar shows "Expanded Control Strip" (at least in Mac OS Catalina)
3. Enable the Touch Bar in Karabiner as a separate "No product name" LED keyboard in the Devices panel.
4. Add the following to the list of complex_modifications rules in karabiner.json

```
{
    "description": "Cmd+DimBrightness Toggles Screen Mirroring Shortcut",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "description": "Cmd+DimBrightness Toggles Screen Mirroring Shortcut (map to display_brightness_decrement). Requires enabling the Touch Bar as a keyboard in Karabiner. See https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1700 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2793101",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "f1",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "open '/System/Applications/Utilities/MirrorDisplays.app'"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```