# Fastest way to enabling screen mirroring on Sierra with the touch strip

Tags: macos, preferences, mirroring

People,

The classical `Command + F1` does not work to do screen mirroring macs with the touch bar running Sierra.

Also, although in the System Preferences I have "Show mirroring options..." enabled, the option still does not appear in the menu when I'm connected to an external screen with VGA.

Thus I have to every time go through: `Open System Preferences -> Select Display -> Select Arrangement -> Click on Checkbox`. This is horrible.

In the absence of the old shortcut, what's the fastest way to enable mirroring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Command–Brightness Down`?

Similar question is [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272271/mbp-touch-bar-mirror-displays-keyboard-shorcut)

Comment: ah. this does work. it still is a bit too tedious since the brightness down button is not always visible. so you have first to expand the action buttons, and then it works with Command-Brightness-Down. good call.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference here.

Another thing that I tried, and which (depending on your touch-bar configuration) could be even faster than the `Command-Decrease Brightness` shortcut is a menu-bar app called Display Menu:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12